# Excel Indirect inside a sumproduct

Tags: excel

I'm pretty new with excel, but I have created a formula to calculate something from data I get from a sensor.

```
=100*((SUMPRODUCT(C16:C98,A16:A98)-SUMPRODUCT(C16:C98,A15:A97)+SUMPRODUCT(C15:C97,A16:A98)-SUMPRODUCT(C15:C97,A15:A97))/53.2)/((SUM(A16:A98)-SUM(A15:A97)))
```

as you can see it's quite long, and the values differ from time to time (sometimes it starts on c16 sometimes on c35,...)
I've tried adding an indirect link in the formula as the following:

original: `SUMPRODUCT(C16:C98,A16:A98)`

added indirect link: `(SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT(M25&":"&M26&","&M27&":"&M28)))`

but this gives me a `#REF!` error.
Does anyone have an idea? Cheers.
B.

Edit: the M25 - M28 are the cells where I'll be putting my starting and ending cell number in. so in this case it would be "C16" in M25, "C98" in M26, "A16" in M27, "A98" in M28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `INDIRECT` for each array, try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT(M25&":"&M26),INDIRECT(M27&":"&M28))
```

Comment: No worries, if you could just mark it as correct it will show as resolved on the main screen to stop other unnecessarily entering the question to help, thanks